# Height relative to screen but fixed

Tags: html, css, resize, viewport-units

I'm trying to make a fixed position div stuck to the bottom of the page, that has the starting height, `70%` of the screen ( `like vh` ).
I will make it resizable with jQuery resizable.

The problem is that if I apply `height: 70vh` or `height: 70%`, the div resizes when the user resizes the browser height, and I want to keep it the same.
Any idea what to do?

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

View the snippet in full page.

Comment: So do you mean, the div is not getting resized? Because when I resize my browser it is getting resized. Can you please elaborate what is expected?

Comment: We can only do this in `js` or `jQuery` or if you want you can set `min-height` to fixed `px` value.

Comment: @nabanita i want it to NOT getting resized.

Comment: @weBer hmm .. i will do it with jquery, but hoped someone will come with a super ideea css-based

Comment: @AdiPîslaru lets see, but there is **none** as far as my knowledge. :)

Comment: @AdiPîslaru if the screen size is small, you want the content to be overlapped with the fixed div?So that you can resize with Jquery, am I correct on it?

Comment: no. i just want a div that is x% percent of the screen height, and if the user wants, will be resizable with js like a textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `vh` or `%` will be relative to the height of the `viewport` or screen height. So we need to set the initial height of the div with JavaScript on DOM load.
2. Next (The resizing part) can be done with CSS `resize` property.
   **PS: In the div bottom right corner you can see the resize icon and do the resizing.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").style.height = window.innerHeight*.7+"px";
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  resize:vertical;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add min-height to div so that it will not resize itself beyond a specific height.

Like this

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 70vh;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```